# MDX Union Resultset

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Please forgive me, I'm new to MDX. I have a problem which I'm really struggling with. I'm trying to build an SSRS report which is grouped by customer. Problem is, the first group is by one set of customers and the second group is everything that's not in the first group. Below is the two scripts I'm trying to join...

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now(),'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Dates].[Day].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 

  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    )
 MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    )  
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %]
  } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY
  {
    [Customer].[Business Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Customer Sales].[Summary Prod Group 1].[Summary Prod Group 1].ALLMEMBERS} On Rows
From
(
    SELECT 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer].&[5637]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[4125]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[1727]
    } ON 0
   ,{[Customer].[Business Type].&[Export]} ON 1
   ,-
      {
        [Customer Sales].[Summary Prod Group 1].&[Missing Product Group]
      } ON 2
From [Sales])
Where
StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    )
```

And...

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now(),'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Dates].[Day].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 

  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    )
 MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    )  
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %]
  } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY
  {
    [Customer].[Business Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Customer Sales].[Summary Prod Group 1].[Summary Prod Group 1].ALLMEMBERS} On Rows
From
(
    SELECT 
    -{
      [Customer].[Customer].&[5637]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[4125]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[1727]
    } ON 0
   ,{[Customer].[Business Type].&[Export]} ON 1
   ,-
      {
        [Customer Sales].[Summary Prod Group 1].&[Missing Product Group]
      } ON 2
From [Sales])
Where
StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    )
```

The only difference between the two scripts is the minus sign where I select the customers.

Please help. Tx.

Comment: Why don't you include all your customers? If I understand your question UNION both sets will produce: `(some customers) UNION (all customers - some customers) = (all customers)`, Is it ok?

Comment: Hi. It's not all the customers. It's a subset of customers based on the business type.